# Log Rotate "Permission Denied" as root via cron

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

I am trying to configure a custom logrotate policy to run every minute as root.  Unfortunately I am getting permission denied from the cron job; but if I run the script manually as root I face no issues.

**custom_logrotate.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/logrotate -f -v /etc/custom_logrotate/custom_logrotate.conf > /var/log/rotate.log 2>&1
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

**/etc/cron.d/custom_logrotate**

```
* * * * * root /etc/custom_logrotate/custom_logrotate.sh
```

**custom_logrotate.conf**

```
/opt/nginx/logs/stdout.log /opt/nginx/logs/perf.log {
        rotate 10
        copytruncate
        nocompress
        size 10M
        start 0
}
```

**Permissions**

```
namei -mo /opt/nginx/logs/
f: /opt/nginx/logs/
 dr-xr-xr-x root root      /
 drwxr-xr-x root root      opt
 drwxr-x--- root gnginx capione
 drwxr-x--- root gnginx logs
```

And the error message.

> error: error opening /opt/nginx/logs/perf.log: Permission denied

**Note**: Running /etc/custom_logrotate/custom_logrotate.sh directly works fine but facing issue just from cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with using `/etc/cron.d` instead of `/var/spool/cron/root` aka crontab.

Seems that even when specifying user as root in `/etc/cron.d` some utilities will still not work properly.